# How to get/set vertical scroll filter property in OBS using C++?

Tags: c++, obs

It is necessary to get/set the value of the vertical speed property. The `verticalSpeed` property has a value of 500 (the maximum value of the slider), but in OBS I manually set 35.

How to get exactly the value 35?

A second question, how can I see all the available filter properties?

```
obs_data_t* source = obs_get_source_by_name("SOURCE_NAME");
obs_data_t* filter = obs_source_get_filter_by_name(source, "FILTER_NAME");
obs_data_t* settings = obs_source_get_settings(filter);
vspeed = obs_data_get_int(settings, "verticalSpeed");
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is an GetSourceFilterInfo function that returns a list of filter properties.
Speed is a parameter speed_x and speed_y.
https://github.com/Palakis/obs-websocket/blob/4.x-current/docs/generated/protocol.md#getsourcefilterinfo